# Filtering data from multible sheets in to a grand total

Tags: excel

Is there a simple way to collate the same data from three sheets into a grand total. My issue is that the data might not be exact on all sheets.

The example would be, I have a list of suppliers on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 with their sales figures beside them in column 2.

Sheet 1 reads

Supplier 1 36
Supplier 2 56
Supplier 3 12
Supplier 4 76

Sheet 2 reads

Supplier 1 23
Supplier 2 48
Supplier 4 16

I would like to create a third sheet that totals all the suppliers so would read

Supplier 1 59
Supplier 2 104
Supplier 3 12
Supplier 4 92

I would usually sort by name and do a simple calculation but as every row won't be identical, this doesn't seem possible. I need it to total the cells with an identical name.

Any help is as always greatly received and much appreciated.

Thank you

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a PivotTable. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120). At #4 add data from your second sheet. (No need to drill down etc.)